# How to connect to ClamAV daemon?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, clam

I'm trying to connect to ClamAV daemon **clamd** on localhost 3310 port via **telnet** comand in terminal:`telnet 127.0.0.1 3310`

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
nIDSESSION [pressed ENTER button on keyboard]
nPING      [pressed ENTER]
```

But it gives error:

```
1: Only nCMDS\n and zCMDS\0 are accepted inside IDSESSION. ERROR
1: Error processing command. ERROR
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Entered **`zPING\0 [pressed ENTER]`** or **`nPING\n`** useless, prompts that error again.
Can you suggest anything?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?!

Comment: @BogdanStoica To hold session with daemon, e.g. write a client on socket that holds session.